# Bash Script Help - Tar not working with variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am trying to backup set folders based on yesterday's date by using a bash script and CRON task.

The folder structure of the site is like this:

```
/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/media/2014/March
```

And I would want to back-up that folder to this file:

```
/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/bk/mediabackup-March-2014.tar.gz
```

So created this script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date -d "12 hours ago" '+%m')

NOWYEAR=$(date -d "12 hours ago" '+%Y')

MONTHS=(Dummy January February March April May June July August September October November December)

NOWMONTH=${MONTHS[3]}

FILE="/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/bk/mediabackup-$NOWMONTH-$NOWYEAR.tar.gz"

PATH="/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/media/$NOWYEAR/$NOWMONTH"

tar -zcvf $FILE $PATH
```

---

When I run this script though shell, I would do this:

```
bash script.sh
```

And it could come up "command not found" - not sure why it's not working?

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Comment: Whats the result of echo ${FILE} and echo ${PATH} ?

Comment: Which command was not found? As for variables, it is the shell that deals with those. The program tar gets the actual values in its command line. (Also "command not found" implies that a command was not found, not that some file path on the command line was invalid)

Comment: You used `PATH` as a variable. You overwrote its default value therefore all commands can't be found, even bash.

Comment: @FreudianSlip - the results are:

/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/bk/mediabackup-March-2014.tar.gz

and

/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/media/2014/March

Comment: Good call @alvits, should have noticed that. That's definitely it.

Comment: Don't use `PATH` as a variable. Replace it with something like `SOURCEPATH` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @alvits - that's fixed it! Great, many thanks! Spent hours trying to figure this out. All works perfectly, thanks for spotting :)!

Comment: Don't use uppercase variable names in the future to avoid namespace collisions.

Comment: @alvits you should post that as an answer since you're the one who spotted it first. :)

Comment: Hi guys, sorry - for some reason this isn't working as a CRON job - no error is being outputted though, so not sure what could be the cause of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By overriding the shell's built-in `PATH` variable, you are causing it to not find the `tar` command. Use another variable name, and generally, refrain from using uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 2):

No need to hard-code the month names:

```
read year month < <(date -d "12 hours ago" "+%Y %B")
echo "$month-$year"
```

```
March-2014
```

Comment: Helpful, but it doesn't actually answer the question.