# How can i use any bash command in bash function

Tags: bash, function, shell, cat, ls

I am trying to use ls , cat etc commands inside a bash function

```
Report()
{
    ls $1 |  sort -u
}
Report()
```

I am getting ls: command not found error when I run the function

Is it not possible to use bash commands inside bash function?

I could see examples where only echo is used inside the function

Comment: When calling a function in bash, you shouldn't use the parentheses. They're used only in its definition.

Comment: How do you run the script? What's the contents of `$PATH` when it runs?

Comment: Sorry added braces while calling function, if I pass path as an argument?
Report()
{
    ls $1 |  sort -u
}
Report "$PATH" 

or 

Report()
{
    ls ../../../ |  sort -u
}
Report 

Ls or sort , none are working for me in function

Comment: @pratheekshalp Did you assign something to `PATH`? If so, you probably broke it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732034/bash-script-help-tar-not-working-with-variables/), especially tripleee's answer.

Comment: `Report(){ ls "${1:-.}" | sort -u; }; Report;`

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function in bash, you shouldn't use the parentheses

```
Report()
{
    ls $1 |  sort -u
};
Report;
```

Comment: The semicolons are superfluous.

Comment: You should quote variables so that their content is not mangled (glob expansion, wordsplitting, etc. eg. `Report '/path/with space and *'`). In this case, something more sophisticated than simple quoting is needed, since it appears not passing the parameter at all is desired to be supported.